# Json encocde Mix of array with objects converted all in array only

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

My php function returns an array that I converted into json using

`$req = json_encode($questionData);`

then passed this to other function and decoded 
`$res = json_decode($req);`

It return me an array including all indexes in array format. 
Even in request array  $questionData has object on some index, those should be in object after jason encode and decode execution.

I want to get same array which has mix of data of arrya and object.

Below is request array

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [pagename] => RC1_PGR_Questions
    [result] => Array
        (
            [CurrentInsuranceStatus] => Array
                (
                    [QuestionData] => Platform_Form_Page_Question Object
                        (
                            [_answer] => 
                            [_answerOptions] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340280
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 1
                                            [_order] => 110
                                            [_promptText] => Yes
                                            [_value] => Y
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340290
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 120
                                            [_promptText] => Yes, on parent's policy
                                            [_value] => Parents
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340300
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 130
                                            [_promptText] => Yes, insured through employer
                                            [_value] => Company
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340310
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 140
                                            [_promptText] => No, policy lapsed/expired
                                            [_value] => Lapsed
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340320
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 150
                                            [_promptText] => No, never been insured
                                            [_value] => Never
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340330
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 160
                                            [_promptText] => No, I didn't have a vehicle to insure
                                            [_value] => First
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [6] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340340
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 170
                                            [_promptText] => No, been deployed/overseas in the military
                                            [_value] => Military
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [7] => Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340350
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 180
                                            [_promptText] => No, other reason
                                            [_value] => Other
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [_answersDivID] => html_CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_phoneAreaField] => 
                            [_attributeName] => CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_criteriaBasedQuestion] => 1
                            [_dateField] => 
                            [_eventHandler] => 
                            [_fieldType] => select
                            [_hideQuestion] => 1
                            [_monthField] => 
                            [_phoneNumberField] => 
                            [_order] => 10000
                            [_pageAttributes] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [additionalLabel] => 
                                    [answerStyle] => 
                                    [colNum] => 
                                    [colWidth] => 
                                    [cssclass] => 
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [isMultiSelect] => 
                                    [maxLength] => 
                                    [min] => 
                                    [questionSkinStyle] => 
                                    [toolTip] => 
                                )

                            [_phonePreFixField] => 
                            [_questionDivID] => prompt_CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_questionKey] => 7169010
                            [_required] => 1
                            [_text] => Current insurance status
                            [_yearField] => 
                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Response array

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [pagename] => RC1_PGR_Questions
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CurrentInsuranceStatus] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [QuestionData] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_answer] => 
                            [_answerOptions] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340280
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 1
                                            [_order] => 110
                                            [_promptText] => Yes
                                            [_value] => Y
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340290
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 120
                                            [_promptText] => Yes, on parent's policy
                                            [_value] => Parents
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340300
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 130
                                            [_promptText] => Yes, insured through employer
                                            [_value] => Company
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340310
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 140
                                            [_promptText] => No, policy lapsed/expired
                                            [_value] => Lapsed
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340320
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 150
                                            [_promptText] => No, never been insured
                                            [_value] => Never
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340330
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 160
                                            [_promptText] => No, I didn't have a vehicle to insure
                                            [_value] => First
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [6] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340340
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 170
                                            [_promptText] => No, been deployed/overseas in the military
                                            [_value] => Military
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [7] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [_answerKey] => 340350
                                            [_hideAnswer] => 
                                            [_order] => 180
                                            [_promptText] => No, other reason
                                            [_value] => Other
                                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [_answersDivID] => html_CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_phoneAreaField] => 
                            [_attributeName] => CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_criteriaBasedQuestion] => 1
                            [_dateField] => 
                            [_eventHandler] => 
                            [_fieldType] => select
                            [_hideQuestion] => 1
                            [_monthField] => 
                            [_phoneNumberField] => 
                            [_order] => 10000
                            [_pageAttributes] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [additionalLabel] => 
                                    [answerStyle] => 
                                    [colNum] => 
                                    [colWidth] => 
                                    [cssclass] => 
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [isMultiSelect] => 
                                    [maxLength] => 
                                    [min] => 
                                    [questionSkinStyle] => 
                                    [toolTip] => 
                                )

                            [_phonePreFixField] => 
                            [_questionDivID] => prompt_CurrentInsuranceStatus
                            [_questionKey] => 7169010
                            [_required] => 1
                            [_text] => Current insurance status
                            [_yearField] => 
                            [_errorLog] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )



        )

)
```

Comment: never saw that json_decode returns assoc array on JSON-Object declared by `{...}` when param 2 (assoc) is not set - why use of `json_decode(json_encode())`? - try `json_decode($req,false)`

Comment: Anyways default is false, Either I get all index in array or Object. i want same as I had in request.

Comment: so what u want is after the json parsing the keys in _answerOptions returns as Platform_Form_Page_Question_AnswerOption for example? i think thats not possible cause json only can handy a (stdclass) object or an int-indexed array

Comment: Yes, I am expecting that. or any other way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

so after i realised what you realy want to do i just uses `serialize` and `unserialize` as alternatives to the JSON-functions like the following working example:

```
class testobj {

    public function __get($name) {
        if(isset($this->{$name}))
            return $this->{$name};
        return false;
    }

    public function __set($name,$val) {
        $this->{$name} = $val;
    }
}

$test = new testobj();
$test->testvar = "testval";

echo print_r($test,true);

/* Output:
testobj Object
(
    [testvar] => testval
)
*/

$test = serialize($test);
echo $test;

/* Output:
O:7:"testobj":1:{s:7:"testvar";s:7:"testval";}testobj Object
*/

$test = unserialize($test);

echo print_r($test,true);

/* Output:
testobj Object
(
    [testvar] => testval
)
*/

echo $test->testvar; // outputs "testval"
```

i think `serialize()` and and `unserialize()` are not that fast as JSON de-/encoding (i've never tested/benchmarked this) but it stores object names in itself. I dont know if it works for classes/objects with methods to, but for your data above it will work. Also with the multidimensional structure, too.

Comment: my main array have objects, will it give array of objects.

Comment: u can mix them like u want to, object in array in object in array or something else, even if its like object, object, array, object it'll work